# agm-circle angular 4 drag sensitivity so fast

Tags: angular, angular-google-maps

I am using agm-circle in agm-map in angular 4. It works fine but the problem is that it move so fast when i dragged it. How to slow it down. Here is my code

```
<agm-map id="map" [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
                <agm-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></agm-marker>
                <agm-circle
                [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"
                [circleDraggable]="true"
                [editable]="true"
                [fillColor]="circleColor"
                (radiusChange)="radiusChange($event)"
                (centerChange)="centerChange($event)"
                [radius]="locationRadius"
            >
            </agm-circle>
            </agm-map>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with centerChange event which makes it fast. You can get your desire result by adding agm-marker event dragEnd to get lat and lng and make markerDraggable true to drag marker. Here is example code you can use.

```
 <agm-map 
      id="map" 
      [latitude]="lat" 
      [longitude]="lng"
      [zoom]="zoom"
      [disableDefaultUI]="false"
      [zoomControl]="false"

      >
          <agm-marker [latitude]="lat"
          [markerDraggable] = "true"
          (dragEnd) = "centerChange($event)"
          [longitude]="lng"></agm-marker>
          <agm-circle
          [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"
          [circleDraggable]="true"
          [editable]="true"
          [fillColor]="circleColor"
          (radiusChange)="radiusChange($event)"
          [radius]="locationRadius"
          (dragEnd)="centerChange($event)"
      >
      </agm-circle>
      </agm-map>
```

Here is the reference link you can find out more details.

[Reference Link](https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/directives/agmmarker)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.